# Dates overlapping scenario

Tags: sql, datetime

TableA (id int, match1 char,match2 char,match3 char,startdate datetime,enddate,status char)

```
id match1  match2  match3  startdate   enddate
1  AAA     BBB     CCC     2006-01-01  2007-01-01 
2  AAA     BBB     CCC     2006-12-12  2008-01-01
3  AAA     BBB     CCC     2008-01-01  2012-02-02

4  DDD     EEE     FFF     2009-01-01  2012-01-01
5  DDD     EEE     FFF     2013-01-01  2020-01-01
```

Ref TableB (match1 char, match2, match3, startdate datetime,  enddate)

```
match1  match2 match3  startdate   enddate
AAA     BBB    CCC     2006-01-01  2015-01-01
DDD     EEE    FFF     2009-01-01  2015-01-01
```

Okay so [Stat] is NULL, I have to populate stat with 'FAIL' in tableA when:

1) For matching match1,match2,match3 in tableB, the dates(start and end) exists outside the scope. Lets see ID=5 effectivedates = 2013 - 2020 but in its ref table, its 2009-2015 so ID = 5 gets the 'fail'.

2) In a set, set is records when match1, match2, match3 are equal so ID 123 is one set and ID 4&5 is another set. So, In a set, effective dates (start and end) dates overlap. even though set 1 (ID1,2,3) exists within the date range of its corresponding record in the reference table, but effective dates of ID = 2 overlaps the effective dates of ID = 1, so ID=2 gets the 'FAIL'

Expected result:

```
id match1  match2  match3  startdate   enddate     stat
1  AAA     BBB     CCC     2006-01-01  2007-01-01  NULL
2  AAA     BBB     CCC     2006-12-12  2008-01-01  FAIL
3  AAA     BBB     CCC     2008-01-01  2012-02-02  NULL
4  DDD     EEE     FFF     2009-01-01  2012-01-01  NULL
5  DDD     EEE     FFF     2013-01-01  2020-01-01  FAIL
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Take the first as ok and "fail" the next overlaping(s).

Comment: In your second scenario where IDs 1 and 2 overlap, how do you decide to "fail" the row with ID 2 rather than the row with ID 1? Do you always fail the row with the later start date in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tableA SET [status] = 'FAIL'
FROM tableB 
WHERE tableB.match1 = tableA.match1 
AND tableB.match2 = tableA.match2 
AND tableB.match3 = tableA.match3
AND tableA.startDate >= tableB.startDate 
AND tableA.endDate <= tableB.endDate
```

EDIT (I thought I might be oversimplifying)
EDIT2 - changed second WHERE

```
SELECT  --  Things outside of allowed date range
id 
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB ON TableB.match1 = TableA.match1 
    AND TableB.match2 = TableA.match2
    AND TableB.match3 = TableA.match3 
WHERE TableA.startDate < TableB.startDate 
    OR TableA.endDate > TableB.endDate 
UNION 
SELECT  --  Things with overlapping date ranges
TableA2.id 
FROM TableA    
JOIN TableA AS TableA2 ON TableA2.match1 = TableA.match1
    AND TableA2.match2 = TableA.match2      
    AND TableA2.match3 = TableA.match3    
WHERE TableA2.startDate BETWEEN TableA.startDate AND TableA.endDate 
    OR TableA2.endDate BETWEEN TableA.startDate AND TableA.endDate
    OR (TableA2.startDate < TableA.startDate AND TableA2.endDate > TableA.endDate)
```

Comment: ANDREW: Your code is failing ID 1,2,3,4 whereas it should fail only 2 and 5.

Comment: Also, we have to match enddate od id1 with startdate of id2 and so forth in a [set], your code doesn't seems to do this. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I found another loophole here for case1. lets assume for ids 1 2 3 dates are 2006-2008, 2012-2014, 2009-2010 . Now even though the dates does'nt overlap each other and exists in the range of its reference record, It will still fail id=3 coz TableA2.startDate < TableA.endDate , You know what I meant or should I explain more ?

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH CandidateIDs AS (
    SELECT  idOriginal = YourTable.id, idFailCandidate = ed.id
    FROM    YourTable
            INNER JOIN YourTable ed ON ed.match1 = YourTable.match1
                               AND ed.match2 = YourTable.match2
                               AND ed.startdate BETWEEN YourTable.startdate AND YourTable.enddate
                               AND ed.id <> YourTable.id
)                              
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  idFailCandidate
            FROM    CandidateIDs r1
            WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CandidateIDs WHERE CandidateIDs.idFailCandidate = r1.idOriginal)
        ) fail ON fail.idFailCandidate = YourTable.id
```

**Test script**

```
;WITH YourTable (id, match1, match2, startdate, enddate, status) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'AAA', 'BBB', CAST('2006-01-01' AS DATETIME), CAST('2007-01-01' AS DATETIME), NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'AAA', 'BBB', '2006-12-12', '2008-01-01', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'AAA', 'BBB', '2008-01-01', '2012-02-01', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'AAA', 'BBB', '2002-01-01', '2004-01-01', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'DDD', 'EEE', '2009-01-01', '2012-01-01', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'DDD', 'EEE', '2011-01-01', '2020-01-01', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'DDD', 'EEE', '2013-01-01', '2015-01-01', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 8, 'DDD', 'EFG', '2009-01-01', '2012-01-01', NULL
)
, CandidateIDs AS (
    SELECT  idOriginal = YourTable.id, idFailCandidate = ed.id
    FROM    YourTable
            INNER JOIN YourTable ed ON ed.match1 = YourTable.match1
                               AND ed.match2 = YourTable.match2
                               AND ed.startdate BETWEEN YourTable.startdate AND YourTable.enddate
                               AND ed.id <> YourTable.id
)                              
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  idFailCandidate
            FROM    CandidateIDs r1
            WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CandidateIDs WHERE CandidateIDs.idFailCandidate = r1.idOriginal)
        ) fail ON fail.idFailCandidate = YourTable.id
```