# SQL Server: Overlapping dates in the same table

Tags: sql, datetime, overlapping

```
TableA (
    id int, 
    match1 char,
    match2 char,
    startdate datetime,
    enddate,
    status char
)
```

Sample data:

```
 id match1  match2   startdate   enddate        Status
 1  AAA     BBB      2006-01-01  2007-01-01 
 2  AAA     BBB      2006-12-12  2008-01-01
 3  AAA     BBB      2008-01-01  2012-02-02
 4  AAA     BBB      2002-01-01  2004-01-01
 5  DDD     EEE      2009-01-01  2012-01-01
 6  DDD     EEE      2011-01-01  2020-01-01
 7  DDD     EEE      2013-01-01  2015-01-01
 8  DDD     EFG      2009-01-01  2012-01-01
```

I have to populate `status` with `'FAIL'` in `tableA` when for matching `match1, match2`, the dates - start and end - overlap each other.

When `ID = 2`, effective dates are `2006-12-12` to `2008-01-01`, which overlaps `ID = 1`. So, `ID = 2` gets the `'FAIL'`. Same is true with `ID = 6`.

Expected result:

```
 id match1  match2    startdate    enddate        Status
 1  AAA     BBB      2006-01-01  2007-01-01       NULL
 2  AAA     BBB      2006-12-12  2008-01-01       FAIL
 3  AAA     BBB      2008-01-01  2012-02-02       NULL
 4  AAA     BBB      2002-01-01  2004-01-01       NULL    
 5  DDD     EEE      2009-01-01  2012-01-01       NULL
 6  DDD     EEE      2011-01-01  2020-01-01       FAIL
 7  DDD     EEE      2013-01-01  2015-01-01       NULL
 8  DDD     EFG      2009-01-01  2012-01-01       NULL (because It has different match2)
```

Also, we are keeping the first record for same match1 and match2 and failing the new incoming overlapped record.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question...

Comment: Why isn't ID 7 a Fail? It overlaps (intersects) with ID 6.

Comment: Ben -That was a different question. Moreover I didn't get proper solution to that.

Comment: @BhupinderSingh, there isn't a question in this question. No idea why you're having a problem doing this. ALso, have "passed" IDs as `null` is probably a bad idea. You won't know what has previously been tried and "passed" and could have to re-process the entire base. Based on your comments below nulls aren't included in indexes,  another reason to not use them for this.

Comment: Lieven: ID7 is not failing because ID6 has failed and eliminated from our consideration. So, ID 7 has no overlapping dates with the prior records of same match1 and match2. Thanks

Comment: @Lieven, I think he's comparing to the first record only for match1,match2 .. it looks odd :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dates overlapping scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567830/dates-overlapping-scenario)

Comment: Ian: This is similar to "Dates overlaping scenario" but It has a new logic in this. Moreover, there was a big loophole in that solution, if you look down with my last comment. Thanks

Comment: @BhupinderSingh - As this clearly is a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567830/dates-overlapping-scenario), I've answered your original one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE or cursor for this. Recursive CTE approach below.

```
;WITH BaseData(id,match1,match2,startdate,enddate)
     AS (SELECT 1,'AAA','BBB','2006-01-01','2007-01-01' UNION ALL
         SELECT 2,'AAA','BBB','2006-12-12','2008-01-01' UNION ALL
         SELECT 3,'AAA','BBB','2008-01-01','2012-02-02' UNION ALL
         SELECT 4,'AAA','BBB','2002-01-01','2004-01-01' UNION ALL
         SELECT 5,'DDD','EEE','2009-01-01','2012-01-01' UNION ALL
         SELECT 6,'DDD','EEE','2011-01-01','2020-01-01' UNION ALL
         SELECT 7,'DDD','EEE','2013-01-01','2015-01-01' UNION ALL
         SELECT 8,'DDD','EFG','2009-01-01','2012-01-01'    ),
     RecursiveCTE
     AS (SELECT id,
                match1,
                match2,
                startdate,
                enddate,
                CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Status,
                enddate                  AS LastSuccessfulEnd
         FROM   (SELECT *,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY match1, match2 
                                               ORDER BY startdate) RN
                 FROM   BaseData) B
         WHERE  RN = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id,
                match1,
                match2,
                startdate,
                enddate,
                Status,
                LastSuccessfulEnd
         FROM   (
                SELECT B.*,
                       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.match1, B.match2 
                                                   ORDER BY B.startdate),
                       CASE
                         WHEN B.startdate < R.LastSuccessfulEnd THEN 'FAIL'
                       END AS Status,
                       CASE
                         WHEN B.startdate >= R.LastSuccessfulEnd THEN B.enddate
                         ELSE R.enddate
                       END AS LastSuccessfulEnd
                 FROM   BaseData B
                        JOIN RecursiveCTE R
                          ON R.match1 = B.match1
                             AND R.match2 = B.match2
                             AND B.startdate > R.startdate) R
         WHERE  R.rn = 1)
SELECT id,
       match1,
       match2,
       startdate,
       enddate,
       Status
FROM   RecursiveCTE
ORDER  BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't ID 7 a Fail? It overlaps (intersects) with ID 6?
>
> > ID7 is not failing because ID6 has failed and eliminated from our consideration

This point that you made in the comments eliminates a possibility of SQL-only solution, because your definition of `FAIL` becomes recursive. In other words, in order to know if something has failed or not, it is not sufficient to know the `start` and `end` date: you must also know the pass or fail status of the "previous generation" of records.

Here is a query that can help you determine the first overlapping ID, disregarding the "overlaps with failed records do not count" rule:

```
select a.*,(
    select top 1 b.id from tableA b
    where a.match1=b.match1 and a.match2=b.match2
    and a.startdate>b.startdate
    and (case when a.startdate<b.startdate then b.startdate else a.startdate end) <
    (case when a.enddate>b.enddate then b.enddate else a.enddate end)
    order by b.startdate asc
) as OverlappingId
from tableA a
```

It returns these results for the data from your table:

```
1   AAA BBB 2006-01-01  2007-01-01  NULL
2   AAA BBB 2006-12-12  2008-01-01  1
3   AAA BBB 2008-01-01  2012-02-02  NULL
4   AAA BBB 2002-01-01  2004-01-01  NULL
5   DDD EEE 2009-01-01  2012-01-01  NULL
6   DDD EEE 2011-01-01  2020-01-01  5
7   DDD EEE 2013-01-01  2015-01-01  6
8   DDD EFG 2009-01-01  2012-01-01  NULL
```

If you must pay attention to the "overlaps with failed" rule, you need to apply it sequentially; SQL is not very good at it.